# Angular + PrimeNG custom confirmDialog

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to write a custom @component to show confirmation dialogues that always have three configuration variables:
confirmButtonLabel, messageText, acceptFunction.

I aim to transport all these three inside of one "configuration" Object.

This is how the component.ts looks like:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Configuration} from '../../model/confirmModal.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './myConfirmDialog.component.html'
})

export class myConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  accept():void {
   this.configuration.accept();
  }

  @Input()
   configuration: Configuration;
}
```

There's an object holding all the configurations

```
configurations = {  
  config1: {
    confirmButtonLabel: 'Yep',
    message: 'Do you want to confirm?',
    accept: (): void => { alert('confirmed'); }
  },
  config2: {
    confirmButtonLabel: 'Yop',
    message: 'Do you want to confirm 2?',
    accept: (): void => { alert('confirmed 2'); }
  },
 };
```

This i how the component.html looks like:

```
<p-confirmDialog class="my-confirm-dialog" icon="fa fa-question-circle" [message]="configuration.message" #cd>
 <p-footer>
   <p-button label="Cancel" (onClick)="cd.reject()"></p-button>
   <p-button (onClick)="accept()"></p-button>
 </p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>
```

I put the Component in place like this inside the parent.

```
<app-my-confirm-dialog [configuration]="confirmations"></app-my-confirm-dialog>
```

And finally I trigger showing the dialog like this:

```
ngOnInit{
  this.someEntry = {
    label: 'Config1Dialog', 
    command: (event) => this.showMyConfirmDialog(this.configurations.config1);
};}
...
showMyConfirmDialog = (confirmDialog): void => {
  this.confirmLabel = confirmDialog.confirmLabel;
  this.confirmationService.confirm(confirmDialog);
}
```

So what happens now is, that the Message of the dialog is always right but  neither the confirm-button-label nor the on-confirm-function work.
I don't understand angular very much at the moment and didn't find any nice instruction for this case.

Comment: Can you share a plunker or jsfiddle?